# How do I recover or reset a forgotten password

Tags: password

Running a pi 4 with raspian. I dont have a password fro removing or installing software.

How do I reset it without having to delete everything and start again?

Comment: not Raspberry Pi specific ... it is a linux question

Comment: @jsotola: the recovery can be pi sepcific.

Answer (score 2):

If you have root on another linux box and an SD card reader, you can mount the SD card from the pi on that machine, and copy your hashed password from the local machine to the SD card.

You will find your local password in /etc/shadow as the second `:` separated field, or you can generate a new one with tools like `htpasswd` or `openssl passwd -6`

When you mount the SD card, the shadow file on the SD card would be something like `/media/root/etc/shadow`

Be sure to correctly eject the SD card before removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting to a root shell and can repair most problems on the Pi.

1. Append `init=/bin/sh` at the end of `cmdline.txt` and reboot.
2. After booting you will be at the prompt in a root shell.
3. Your root file system is mounted as readonly now, so remount it as
   read/write `mount -n -o remount,rw /`

You can then reset password with `passwd pi` although there are other methods e.g. deleting the password in `/etc/passwd` (which you will find if you search)

4. Remove `init=/bin/sh` and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Some addition to @milliways's answer:

- if you have lost root access to the Pi, you can take-out the SD card and use a different computer to edit the `cmdline.txt`
- the `cmdline.txt` is on the first partition (or `/boot`)
- instead of assigning a new password, you may also add

```
pi  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

at the end of `/etc/sudoers` temporarily, assuming that you can mount the second partition somewhere.