# What should I do if i forgot my authentication password

Tags: software-installation, password

i am running raspbian GNU/linux 10 and forgot the password to download software, is there anything i can do?

Comment: https://raspberrytips.com/forgot-raspberry-pi-password/#:~:text=Once%20the%20session%20opens%2C%20go,t%20know%20the%20current%20password.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover or reset a forgotten password](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/132419/how-do-i-recover-or-reset-a-forgotten-password)